# metersPerUnit for USDZ Entity

Tags: swift, realitykit

I was using `visualBounds(recursive:relativeTo:excludeInactive:)` but realized the result looked incorrect - I opened the USDZ in Reality Convertor and found that the metersPerUnit was 0.01 which was unexpected and making `visualBounds` for this USDZ not make sense when compared entities with metersPerUnit at 1.

I was wondering if we could get the metersPerUnit metadata from a USDZ loaded as an Entity (or even MDLAsset) using Reality Kit?

[image]

[image]